# SqlDependency doesn't fire/trigger event

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, notifications, sqldependency

I have followed some tutorial to send notification to my app when something changes in a table in my SQL Server database. This is my listener class:

```
class dbListener
{
    public dbListener() 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");

        SqlDependency.Stop(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");
        SqlDependency.Start(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");
        connection = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");
        connection.Open();
        SomeMethod();
    }
    SqlConnection connection;
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
        // Create a new SqlCommand object.

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CODVEI FROM dbo.ArchivioErogazioni", connection);
        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        command.Notification = null;  // ---> DO I NEED IT??
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.
        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
        // Execute the command.
        command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    // Handler method
    void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
        MessageBox.Show("ikjkjkj");
        Debug.WriteLine("fkldjkfjklgjf");
        SomeMethod();
    }

    void Termination()
    {
        // Release the dependency.
        SqlDependency.Stop(MainWindow.GetConnectionString("Model"));
    }
}
```

It doesn't fire the event correctly. At the start of the app, it shows me the message box (it is in the event management to test it) once or twice, I don't know why. Then, when I edit the values in the database from SQL Server Management Studio, I get the message box or 0 or 1 or 2 times, then it never fires again.

In my database, I have execute this script:

```
USE master ;
GO
ALTER DATABASE IN4MATICSystem_Pie SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::IN4MATICSystem_Pie to sa;
```

I have surely done a big mistake..... which one??

**UPDATE**:

After the hints of T McKeown, this is my code (still not working, it shows me 2 or 3 message boxes at startup and then nothing):

```
class dbListener
{
    public dbListener() 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");

        SqlDependency.Stop(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");
        SqlDependency.Start(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");
        connection = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=xxx;");
        connection.Open();
        SomeMethod();
    }
    SqlConnection connection;

    SqlCommand command;
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
        // Create a new SqlCommand object.

        if (command == null)
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.ArchivioErogazioni", connection);
            // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        }
        else
        {
            command.Notification = null;  // this cancels any previous notifcation object
        }
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.
        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
        // Execute the command.
        command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    // Handler method
    void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change) 
        { 
            // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
            MessageBox.Show("ikjkjkj");
            Debug.WriteLine("fkldjkfjklgjf");
            SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
            dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange; 
            //dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange;
            SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    void Termination()
    {
        // Release the dependency.
        SqlDependency.Stop(MainWindow.GetConnectionString("Model"));
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
    MessageBox.Show("ikjkjkj");
    Debug.WriteLine("fkldjkfjklgjf");

   SqlDependency dependency =
    (SqlDependency)sender;
    dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange;
    SomeMethod(); //re-register
}
```

Modify `SomeMethod()`:

```
SqlConnection connection;
SqlCommand command;   <-- make command instance var

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
    // Create a new SqlCommand object.

    if ( command == null )
    {
       command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.ArchivioErogazioni", connection);
      // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
    }
    else{
       command.Notification = null;  // this cancels any previous notifcation object
    }
    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    // Maintain the refence in a class member.
    // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
    // Execute the command.
    command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Call this function, does it return true?

```
private bool CanRequestNotifications()
{
// In order to use the callback feature of the
// SqlDependency, the application must have
// the SqlClientPermission permission.
try
{
    SqlClientPermission perm =
        new SqlClientPermission(
        PermissionState.Unrestricted);

    perm.Demand();

    return true;
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere that I need to do it, otherwise the event will be triggered only once... is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, but you never unregistered the listener... look at my edit

Comment: I have copied it, but.... it shows me 3 times the message box at the startup... then, I edit the involved table from the sql server management, but nothing happens.. I have also tried to move the declaration of SqlDependency dependency outside, like an attribute of te class and use it in the init method and in the OnDependencyChange, but it is still the same.

Comment: sorry, but... still nothing! 2 message boxes at startup, then I edit the table but nothing happens....

Comment: I have updated the code in the question with you hints.

Comment: FURTHER: why does it fire at startup, 2 or 3 times?

Comment: i don't know.. i added one last check, i updated my answer... if not i am out of ideas.

Comment: yes, it returns true. What does it mean? If it is true, what am I making wrong?

Comment: I have done another update. The query was wrong, it can't contain the "*" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx). Further, I have inserted the check for the type of notifications. It works well, but only for the two first changes in the database. Something wrong in the managing of the event?